# Running native code on Azure

Tags: azure

I am trying to run a C executable on Azure. I have many workerRoles and they continuously check a Job Queue. If there is a job in the queue, a worker role runs an instance of the C executable as a process according to the command line arguments stored in a job class. The C executable creates some log files normally. I do not know how to access those created files. What is the logic behind it? Where are the created files stored? Can anyone explain me? I am new to azure and C#.

One other problem is that all of the working instances of the C executable need to read a data file. How can I distribute that required file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, realize that in Windows Azure, your worker role is simply running inside a Windows 2008 Server environment (either SP2 or R2). When you deploy your app, you would deploy your C executable as well (or grab it from blob storage, but that's a bit more advanced). To find out where your app lives on disk, call `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot")` - that returns a path. You'd typically have your app sitting in a folder called AppRoot under the role root. You'd find your C executable there.

Next, you'll want your app to write its files to an output directory you specify on the command line. You can set up storage in your local VM with your role's properties. Look at the Local Storage tab, and configure a named local storage area:

[image]

Now you can get the path to that storage area, in code, and pass it as a command line argument:

```
var outputStorage = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyLocalStorage");
var outputFile = Path.Combine(outputStorage.RootPath, "myoutput.txt");
var cmdline = String.Format("--output {0}", outputFile);
```

Here's an example of launching your myapp.exe process, with command line arguments:

```
var appRoot = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot")
            + @"\", @"approot");

var myProcess = new Process()
{
   StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(appRoot, @"myapp.exe"), cmdline)
   {
      CreateNoWindow = false,
      UseShellExecute = false,
      WorkingDirectory = appRoot
   }
};
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Normally you'd set CreateNoWindow to true, but it's easier to debug if you can see the command shell window.

Last thing: Once your app is done creating the file, you'll want to either:

- Process it and delete it (it's not in a durable place so eventually it'll disappear)
- Change your storage to use a Cloud Drive (durable storage)
- Copy your file to a blob (durable storage)

In production, you'll want to add exception-handling, and you can re-route stdout and stderr to be captured. But this sample code should be enough to get you started.

OOPS - one more 'one more thing': When adding your 'myapp.exe' to your project, be SURE to go to its Properties, and set 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy Always' - otherwise your myapp.exe file won't end up in Windows Azure and you'll wonder why things don't work.

EDIT: Pushing results to a blob - a quick example

First get set up a storage account and add to your role's Settings. Say you called it 'AzureStorage' - now set it up in code, get a reference to a blob container, get a reference to a blob within that container, and then perform a file upload to the blob:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("AzureStorage");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer outputfiles = blobClient.GetContainerReference("outputfiles");
        outputfiles.CreateIfNotExist();

        var blobname =  "myoutput.txt";
        var blob = outputfiles.GetBlobReference(blobname);
        blob.UploadFile(outputFile);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also explain me how to collect the created files from local storage? Each worker can copy the created file to a blob. Then some other worker role or a client application can reach that blob right?

Comment: See updated answer for a quick example of pushing the output file to a blob. Again, you'll need exception handling, etc. I recommend downloading the Windows Azure Platform Training Kit to get more details - excellent tutorials and hands-on labs there.

Comment: this is a great answer and i learned a lot from this thread; but the one problem i'm currently facing is getting the output file created. in david's response, there's an assumption of an "--output" flag to specify the output file. what if there isn't a flag? there's an alternative of using process.standardoutput also to get the output as a stream, but that i prefer to use the command output redirection operators ">", ">>", etc. if possible. so the question is: **is using cmd operator possible?** thank you for the additional info.

Answer (score 2):

In Azure land you shouldn't write to the file system. You should write to SQL Azure, Table Storage or most likely in this case Blob storage (basically, I think you should think of blob storage as the old file system)

This is because:

1. You could have multiple instances running and you will end up having different files on different instances (which are just virtual machines)
2. Your instance could potentially be moved at any moment and you would lose the info on the file system as it's not part of your deployment package.

Using one of the three storage options will provide a central repository for all of your instances to access and it will be persisted over a redeployment.

Comment: That's not really true. You have both non-durable and durable file storage to write to. See my answer (in a moment) for more details.

Comment: durable file storage - is that blob storage?

Comment: Yes - in about 10 lines of code, you can mount an NTFS volume as a Cloud Drive. Looks just like a drive letter to your app.

Comment: But totally concur on local file storage - it's great for temporary storage. In the example I showed above, the idea would be to let the app generate output, and then do something with that output (copy it to a blob, process/parse it, whatever) and not count on it sticking around in local storage forever. I often use local storage for processing/output - very convenient, and allows many 3rd-party apps to work unchanged.